# Relative homology is isomorphic to the group $\Gamma_R(A)$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm studying algebraic topology, and I have a question.

> For an $n$-manifold $M$ and a compact subspace $A \subseteq M$, show that $H_n(M | A;R)$ is isomorphic to the group $\Gamma_R(A)$ of sections of the covering space $M_R \rightarrow M$ over A.

I tried this problem to use lemma 3.27 in Hatcher, which is

> Lemma 3.27.(a) : If $x \to \alpha_x$ is a section of the covering space $M_R \to M$, then there is a unique class $\alpha_A \in H_n(M|A;R)$ is $\alpha_x$ for all $x \in A$

This part show the injectiveness, but how to show this is surjective?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** (This is not a complete answer. I will leave all further details, including how to assemble the relevant facts together, to you.)

Start with a section $\psi$ on $A$.

Extend it to an open neighborhood of $A$. (Prove that for each $x \in A$ there is an open neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ and a *unique* section $\varphi_x: U_x \to M_R$ with $\varphi_x|_{U_x \cap A} = \psi|_{U_x \cap A}$, and that this holds true for any open neighborhood of $x$ contained in $U_x$ as well. Then argue using compactness that there is an open set $A \subset U$ and a section $\varphi: U \to M_R$ with $\varphi|_A = \psi$.)

Then use that $H_n(M | A; R) = H_n(U|A;R)$ by excision.